# Матрица в Python

Tags: python

Например, у меня есть матрица из произвольного(Не задающегося в программе) количества столбцов и из произвольного(Не задающегося в программе) количества строчек, как мне прочитать эту матрицу.
Например:
Вход:
1 6 1 (Переход строки)
8 5 2 (Переход строки)
1 3 1 (Переход строки)
И мне надо записать это в переменную как [[1, 6, 1], [8, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1]]

Comment: А что конкретно непонятно? Ввод данных с клавиатуры? Запись в переменную?

Comment: Вы хотите читать из файла? Как программа должна понять, что вы закончили ввод?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_line():
    return list(map(int, input('Введите строку матрицы (числа через пробел): ').split()))


matrix = []

line = get_line()
while line:
    matrix.append(line)
    line = get_line()


print(matrix)
```

Данный код принимает построчно элементы матрицы, до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт пустую строку.